# Mongoose find not working with ObjectId

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have one schema defined in  userref.js

```
module.exports = (function userref() {

    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var newSchema= new Schema([{

        userId: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User',
            index: true
        },
                value: { type: Number }

    }]);

    var results = mongoose.model('UserRef', newSchema);

    return results;

})();
```

I have inserted some data and when I try to fetch some data I am getting proper values from mongodb console

```
db.getCollection('userrefs').find({'userId':ObjectId('57a48fa57429b91000e224a6')})
```

It returns properly some data

Now issue is that when I try to fetch some data in code by giving objectId I am getting empty array. In below function userrefs is returned as empty array

```
//req.params.userId=57a48fa57429b91000e224a6
var UserRef = require('../userref.js');
this.getuserref = function (req, res, next) {

        try {
            var o_userId =mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.userId);
            var query = { userId: o_userId };
            var projection = '_id userId value';

            UserRef.find(query, projection, function (err, usrrefs) {
                if (err) return next(err);
                res.send(usrrefs);
                console.log("userref fetched Properly");
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('Error While Fetching  ' + err);
            return next(err);
        }
    };
```

Also when I debug code I can see o_userId as objectId with id value as some junk character

```
o_userId: ObjectID
_bsontype: "ObjectID"
id: "W¤¥t)¹â$¦"
```

Comment: Do you need an array of userId in one single document? or one userId per document?

Comment: I am getting emty array from code

Comment: Have you tried without casting to ObjectId as mongoose does that for you internally i.e. `var query = { userId: req.params.userId };`?

Comment: in your schema, you have a _id and array of userId and value ?? Do you really need that array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the export like this

```
module.exports.modelname= mongoose.model('userrefs', nameofschema, 'userrefs');     

var z = require('../userref.js');

var UserRef  = z.modelname;
```

Now call using UserRef.

Just simply try this man.

```
Model.find({ 'userId': objectidvariable}, '_id userid etc', function (err, docs) {
      // docs is an array
    });
```

Reference sample copied from their official doc.

Comment: how to create objectidvariable from a string in req.params.userid

Comment: objectidvariable is good to go in string format. Just pass the actual object id in string format. like `123ahehadh13123h`  = this is my object id for example. simply `var objectidvariable = '12312313asdad';`

Comment: @Alien01 I found the problem I guess, it is not about the query itself, it is about how you are querying.

Comment: Not working tried this also .find{'userid':'57a48fa57429b91000e224a6'}

Comment: @Alien01 Look at the changes and give it a try. You need to map the modelname to the value via which you are making the call because in a file there can be various models and not just one.

Comment: where to add module.exports.modelname= mongoose.model('userrefs', nameofschema, 'userrefs');  , I am already returining form that file

Comment: There you go, I have made a pastebin. You'll understand the concept I guess. http://pastebin.com/zYFcrKWG

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
try {
        var o_userId =mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.userId);
        var query = { userId: o_userId };
        var projection = '_id $.userId $.value';

        UserRef.find(query, projection, function (err, usrrefs) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            res.send(usrrefs);
            console.log("userref fetched Properly");
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error While Fetching  ' + err);
        return next(err);
    }
```

Comment: its still giving empty  array

Comment: try `"userId" : o_userId` instead of `userId : o_userId`

Comment: Original answer did not work for me (plan string as _id), but `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)` this did. Thanks !!